# Setting up (Mod_)Mono on Ubuntu 10 with Apache2

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2, mono

Can anyone give me links on some tutorials (or advice) for setting up Mono on Apache2 in Ubuntu?  Most of what I found seems to be missing steps or isn't very clear. (Ended up left with a site that still isn't able to display and I'm certain it's a configuration issue).

Any help would be wonderful.

Comment: What happens if you write "Hello World" in ASP?

Comment: Well...I cant even navigate to the page (I have a sample app up there already).  It just tells me that it does not exist.

Comment: Post your apache configuration for that site...

Answer (score 1):

I guess its too late but one day while i wanted to know this answer i saw someone post this 
http://blog.ruski.co.za/page/Install-Mono-on-Ubuntu.aspx